# Git server under Windows using FreeSSHd

Tags: windows, git, ssh

I'm trying to setup git as server on Windows.

1. Installed freesshd, configured it, and checked ssh from linux machine, it works.
2. Downloaded Git for Windows, and installed it, in PATH added git\bin and git\libexec\git-core
3. Made bare repository in d:\GitRepo\u7.git

when I'm trying

```
git clone serhiy@192.168.75.2:d:/gitrepo/u7.git
```

I get well known "bad line length character: fata".

But typing

```
ssh 192.168.75.2 git-receive-pack d:/gitrepo/u7.git
```

I've got legal answer

> 00900000000000000000000000000000000000000000 capabilities^{} report-status delete-refs side-band-64k quiet ofs-delta agent=git/1.8.1.msysgit.1
>   0000

What can be wrong?
As I understood i can't get to the correct folder while "git clone", I tried ssh://, sh.exe instead of cmd.exe, tried cmd /K "d: && cd \gitrepo" то set the current folder, and nothing. But I have working git-receive-pack d:/gitrepo/u7.git.
Do I need to point current folder for the repository?

**UPDATE:**
After reading a last post in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092583/how-to-stop-git-via-ssh-on-windows-from-resolving-the-wrong-path) I've created pointed files and cloned project

Create file gup.sh with line

> git-upload-pack.exe $*

and grp.sh with

> git-receive-pack.exe $*

on server!

Then clone repository

```
git clone -u 'sh gup.sh' ssh://serhiy@192.168.75.2/d/gitrepo/u7.git
```

and set some configs

```
git config --global remote.origin.uploadpack 'sh gup.sh'
git config --global remote.origin.receivepack 'sh grp.sh'
```

It seems it work under linux.
Under windows I cannot just login, have Permession denied.

**UPDATE:**
Since I've moved to using RSA keys, everything works, so 
I have:

1. Windows Server 2003
2. Installed FreeSHHd on it
3. Access from Linux and Windows machines to Git repositorie using RSA authentication.
4. As shell on server I use git's sh.exe
5. A wierd way to clone repository first time git clone -u 'sh gup.sh' ssh://192.168.75.2/d/gitrepo/u7.git

Comment: I would recommend using Gerrit: http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/. After simple configuration it works as a simple Git-server.

Comment: have you tried `192.168.75.2:/d/gitrepo/u7.git`

Comment: Yes, I've tried, and had the same result. Now trying to put git repository in the git installation folder...

Comment: You should really think about switching the server to linux if you can. Gitolite is an awesome tool!

Comment: Definitely think about upgrading since freesshd has a known vulnerability: http://threatpost.com/tag/freesshd

Comment: You are right. The world is not as safe as before.